# React native how to update multiple state values

Tags: react-native

Here is the user details which I want to update values when user enters data in Textinput

```
const [details, setDetails] = React.useState({
        isValidName: true,
        isValidMobile: true,
        isValidEmail: true,
        isValidGSTIN: true,
        isValidPAN: true,
        name: '',
        mobile: '',
        email: '',
        company: '',
        baddr1: '',
        baddr12: '',
        bcity: '',
        bpincode: '',
        bstate: ' TAMIL NADU',
        bcountry: 'INDIA',
        saddr1: '',
        saddr2: '',
        sbranch: '',
        sgstin: '',
        scity: '',
        spincode: '',
        sstate: '',
        scountry: '',
        pan: '',
        gstin: '',
        userlevel: '',
      });
```

//In this method i am updating values each time when user enters data

```
const submitBillAddress = (data, type) => {
    console.log('bill', type);
    switch(type){
      case 'addr1':
        setDetails((prevState)=>{
          return({
            ...prevState,
            baddr1: data
          });
        });
      break;
    }
    console.log('billdetails', details);
  };

 return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
        placeholder="Address Line 1"
        value={sameAddress?null:details.baddr1}
        onChangeText={val => submitBillAddress(val, 'addr1')}
      />
    </View>
)
```

I am new to React Native application development and I know this question is basic but I am not getting exact output. Here I have one Textinput in which I am entering data that I wanted to store in details.

The issue is if I enter data in textinput it's not updating value in details. Let's say I am entering 'C' in Textinput if I try to check the value in console the value of details.baddr1='' it's empty, Second time if I enter value 'H' on that time in console the value of details.baddr1='C'. Instead of showing the value details.baddr1='CH' it's showing previously entered value.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The values are actually updated correctly. The catch here is that the setDetails is asynchronous. Move log to a useEffect instead

Comment: Your spelling and attention to detail is consistently atrocious. Please consider making a modicum of effort when posting here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is for a form of some sort. In that case, a package is your best bet I believe. While what you're trying to achieve is possible without a package, using a package is far less painful in the long run for your app.

Please check out [formik](https://formik.org/) or [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/).

They're both decent.